# I have followed the api documentation for Watson Tone analyser to no avail - can't connect the two endpoints

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson

I have a Watson Tone cloud service up and running and I am trying to link it to my index.js file. However it doesn't seem to want to connect.

Code below:

```js
const ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3');

const toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
 version: '2017-09-21',
 iam_apikey: 'omoNirDx1MUQwCdlHTQ-5Fxklx2_c0dUVAyMFIItFLty',
 url: 'http://watson-row-analyser.eu-gb.cf.appdomain.cloud/#'
});
const text =
 'Team, I know that times are tough! Product ' +
 'sales have been disappointing for the past three ' +
 'quarters. We have a competitive product, but we ' +
 'need to do a better job of selling it!';

const toneParams = {
 tone_input: { text: text },
 content_type: 'application/json'
};

toneAnalyzer
 .tone(toneParams)
 .then((toneAnalysis) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(toneAnalysis, null, 2));
 })
 .catch((err) => {
  console.log('error:', err);
 });
```

Current error code:

```
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:npm-global marcwatts$ node index1.js
error: { Not Found: Not Found
    at formatError (/Users/marcwatts/Desktop/mxw817/DBTestApp/npm-global/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/requestwrapper.js:111:17)
    at /Users/marcwatts/Desktop/mxw817/DBTestApp/npm-global/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/requestwrapper.js:259:19
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'Not Found',
  code: 404,
  message: 'Not Found',
  body:
   '"<!DOCTYPE html>\\n<html lang=\\"en\\">\\n<head>\\n<meta charset=\\"utf-8\\">\\n<title>Error</title>\\n</head>\\n<body>\\n<pre>Cannot POST /</pre>\\n</body>\\n</html>\\n"',
  headers:
   { 'x-backside-transport': 'FAIL FAIL',
     connection: 'close',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'none\'',
     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
     date: 'Sat, 06 Jul 2019 15:32:34 GMT',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-powered-by': 'Express',
     'x-global-transaction-id': 'ba9308f85d20bf12a70673ff' } }
```

Link to api for Watson:

```
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer?code=node
```

Code 404 means Not Found. A requested item or parameter does not exist. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it on Ibm cloud? If so your `url` is wrong.

Comment: How can you tell it is wrong? I can only see two URLs on my dashboard for the app: 1. the one in the credentials of the service 2. the url of the service itself (in this post). I have tried both but they both have the same error

Comment: See: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer#service-endpoint